# Parsing XML file to run Labview Program

Tags: xml, labview

I have been given XML-Files that are to be used to run a machine, the interface is via Labview. So far, I have only found Labview parsing that relates to XML data structures, where the nodes are known and always have the same amount of data. In my case, the XML is comprised of a number of "steps" and "conditions", where the steps are to be completed one after the other and the next step is only started when "conditions" are fulfilled. The XML format is like this.

```
<header attribute_1>
    <headerNode_1>value_1</headerNode_1>
    <headerNode_2>value_2</headerNode_2>
</header>

<step id="1">
    <condition>
         <conditionToBeChecked_1>Condition_Value_1</conditionToBeChecked_1>
    </condition>
    <DoThings>
        <ThingToDo_1>Thing_Value_1</ThingToDo_1>
        <ThingToDo_2>Thing_Value_2</ThingToDo_2>
    </DoThings>
</step>

<step id="2">
    <condition>
         <conditionToBeChecked_2>Condition_Value_2</conditionToBeChecked_2>
         <conditionToBeChecked_3>Condition_Value_3</conditionToBeChecked_3>
    </condition>
    <DoThings>
        <ThingToDo_3>Thing_Value_3</ThingToDo_3>
        <ThingToDo_4>Thing_Value_4</ThingToDo_4>
        <ThingToDo_5>Thing_Value_5</ThingToDo_5>
    </DoThings>
</step>
```

ad infinitum...

I am still wondering how to start. I could either convert this into a string and look for specific keywords, or build a highly convoluted case structure and try to catch all nodes linearly. Are there any more elegant options?

Answer (score 0):

Labview has some native XML schemes (look in the examples and browse for XML), but I do not think they will be helpful.

There two toolboxes that can do the job, some tweaking is necessary though. I would recommend the one from github, since the NI one is more for native datatypes.

- https://github.com/JKISoftware/JKI-EasyXML
- http://www.ni.com/example/31330/en/#toc1

To make you live simple, I would first remove all the _1 and such for easier recognition.

Comment: Hi, the problem with the native schemes and the toolboxes is that you need to know the data format ahead of time (which is, of course, the whole point of XML). Unfortunately, in my case, each step can have a different amount of conditions and things to do, so I cannot use a predefined data type. BTW: the _1 is just pseudocode, in the real program, they have specific names.